# Laravel 5 Steam Login Redirect Loop

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5, steam

I'm trying to setup a clean install of Laravel 5 to allow users to authenticate via Steam. I've found and have been using this steam auth package for Laravel 5 - https://github.com/invisnik/laravel-steam-auth and have also been following this tutorial on how to get it working - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfHX-Hecu3k

However, I've hit a minor issue... It's mostly working, however, when I try to log in, it takes me to the steam page, and then once I hit the "sign in" button on the steam community login page and it sends me back to the website, the website then redirects me straight back to the steam community login page...

---

I know the issue is most likely in the app/Http/controllers/AuthController.php (see below for code screenshot). After some further debugging (i.e. putting some file_put_contents around the code), the code inside the

`if ($this->steam->validate()){
...
}`

does not appear to be triggering. I'm not sure why though...

---

EDIT: $this->steam->validate() seems to be returning 'null' when I json_encode and file_put_content it's output...

---

I've been using Laravel for a total of about 30 minutes, and it's also the first MVC I have used, so am fairly newbish at it, however, trying to learn how it's systems work.

app/Http/controllers/AuthController.php (I have changed 'App\User' to 'test\User' since this screenshot was taken)

[image: authController]

config/steam-auth.php (api key removed for upload)

[image: steamauth]

app/Http/routes.php

[image: routes]

Section of app/Http/controllers/Auth/AuthController.php

[image: authauthcontroller]

database/migrations/...create_users_table.php

[image: migrations]

Section of config/app.php

[image: providers]

Section of composer.json

[image: composer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I watched a laracast on laravel, and also a refresher on OOP, I then realised I was doing a few things wrong...

- Namespaces need to be "App\"... (not the name of the app)
- The steam auth needed to go in "require", not "require-dev" in composer.json
- added the id auto-increment back in

Everything now works! :D
Need to figure out how to remove the id autoincrement and make it use the steamid, but eh, I'll figure that out eventually